# How to insert data from a show page of one model to a pivot table in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to fill a pivot table with the user_id of the current user and event_id of the event that the user is viewing. But on clicking submit the page shows The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again. Here is my code:

EventController.php

```
    public function index()
    {
        $events = DB::table('events')->get();
        return view('events.index', ['events'=>$events]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('events.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $event = new Event;
        $event->title = $request->eventTitle;
        $event->location = $request->eventLocation;
        $event->date = $request->eventDate;
        $event->time = $request->eventTime;

        $event->save();
        Session::flash('success', 'Event created successfully');
        return redirect()->route('events.create');
    }


    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $event = Event::find($id);
        return view('events.show', ['event'=>$event]);
    }
```

EventsUsersController.php

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $event_id = $request->id;
    $user_id = $request->Auth::user()->id;

    DB::table('event_user')->insert([
        ['event_id' => $event_id],
        ['user_id' => $user_id]
    ]);
}
```

and the show page from where I want to insert data into the pivot table

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
    <h1>{{$event->title}}</h1>
    <p>Date: {{$event->date}}</p>
    <p>Time: {{$event->time}}</p>
    <p>Location: {{$event->location}}</p>
    @if(Auth::check())
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('eventsusers.store') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="event_id" value="{{ $event->id }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Register</button>
</form>
@endif
    </div>
@endsection
```

My migration file for user_event table:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('event_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('event_id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->primary(['event_id', 'user_id']);
        });
    }
```

I am new to laravel. So please be gentle. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

csrf token can create this type of problem. There are several ways to solve it.

1. Add `{{ csrf_field() }}` inside your form like below code & check what happens.

   {{ csrf_field() }}
       Register
2. You can add a hidden field like this `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">`
3. You can update VerifyCsrfToken middleware using this approach

   protected $except = [
           'your/route'
       ];

Comment: now it is giving me "Class name must be a valid object or a string" error in EventsUsersController

Comment: moreover, where is your event_id($request->id) inside your form?

Comment: Most of the errors were being caused by imports that I had 
 not made and the way I used $request->Auth::.. instead of just Auth:: No it is giving me a new error, which I think is related to the way my database has been created. "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `event_user` (`event_id`) values (), (1))"

Comment: try to solve your problem sequentially, it's showing this error. Because there is no value for user_id when you try to insert it

Comment: Then there should be a problem with the syntax I am using to collect the user_id in show.blade.php because if the user is not logged in the form would not even show.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172327/discussion-between-jobayer-and-subhadeep-sarkar).

Comment: both input field name are same(event_id), it should be different. You can use user_id for another one.

Then write $user_id = $request->user_id;

Comment: also need to change first time too like $event_id = $request->event_id;

Comment: try dd($user_id) & check whether it has right value or not

Comment: yes it has: POST Data
_token 
"O2hTAEPwOd8Bz8Adquwl4x9JdC1ly101ro9Y9Tfk"
event_id 
"3"
user_id 
"1"

Comment: DB::table('event_user')->insert([
        'event_id' => $event_id,
        'user_id' => $user_id
    ]);

try this code

Comment: removed the second square bracket but now it is not getting event_id value: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'event_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `event_user` (`event_id`, `user_id`) values (, 1))

Comment: it means event_id has no value

Comment: another way to do it DB::table('event_user')->insert([ 'event_id' => $request->event_id, 'user_id' => $request->user_id ]);